# DOM parse, how to remove special Chars?

Tags: php, dom

I am getting a string:

```
$a="Delivered\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t01/28/2011";
```

I want

```
$v="Delivered@01/28/2011";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually have a string, you can remove any white space character with a regular expression:

```
$a = preg_replace("/\s+/", '', trim($a));
```

or, as you want `@` in the string:

```
$a = preg_replace("/\s+/", '@', trim($a));
```

But whether this works depends on your input. If it is always like given above, it should be fine.

Reference: [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: @James PHP: Don't ask me whether it is not working. If it is not working, then you should describe what the output is and what you expect or which error you get. *its not working* is hardly helpful. For the record: This code works perfectly given the input above (note that I edited my answer in between, so make sure you tried the latest version)

Answer (score 0):

use $a = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $a) and after use $a = preg_replace('/\s+/', '@', $a).

what tool is used for parsing?

Comment: sorry, replace $a = preg_replace('/\S+/', ' ', $a)  to $a = preg_replace('/\s+/', need symbol, $a)